# Environment Variables In A Shopify React Project

Tags: node.js, reactjs, environment-variables, shopify, vite

How To Load My Environment Variables In A Shopify React Project?

backend  - node /
frontend - react using vite

I need to create a dotenv file and load the vars in the frontend app.

thanks in advance

Comment: Are you referring to declaring your .env variables in the node project and serve them in React app?